# Setting the location of dynamic textboxes drawn

Tags: vb.net

I have a main form that allows the user the create questions for a questionaire.  When the form opens up, the form will be blank with a button to "Add Questions and answers"  This button will open up a new form where the user can set up the questions and answers.  Once the user enters in the first question and answer, they will be taken back to the main screen and the first question and answer will be populated on that main screen.  This works exactly the way I need it to.  The problem is that when I want to enter a second question and answer, I need that question and answer to be placed below the first one, but instead, it overwrites the first one.  I need to somehow add a counter to my "Add Questions and answers" button so that once the new form opens up, I can set the dynamically created textboxes at a new location.
I just don't know how to add this counter, since each time I click the button, a new form is created, and the value of the counter will always start at 0.

Any suggestions?

Here is my function to dynamically display my results to the main screen:

```
 Public Function SaveInfo()
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
    Dim frmQuest As New frmAddCSIQuestions()
    Dim values() As String = lstAnswers.Items.Cast(Of String).ToArray
    txtList.Name = "txt"
    txtQuest.Name = "txtQuest"
    txtType.Name = "txtType"
    txtList.Size = New Point(300, 20)
    txtQuest.Size = New Point(300, 20)
    txtType.Size = New Point(100, 20)
    txtQuest.Text = txtQuestion.Text
    If rdbFreeText.Checked = True Then
        txtType.Text = rdbFreeText.Text
    ElseIf rdbDropDown.Checked = True Then
        txtType.Text = rdbDropDown.Text
    End If

    If bFirstRowAdded Then
        frmQuest.TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount += 1
    End If
    bFirstRowAdded = True
    frmQuest.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtQuest)
    frmQuest.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtType)
    frmQuest.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtList)
    txtList.Text = String.Join(",", values)
    Me.Hide()
    frmQuest.ShowDialog()
End Function
```

Comment: How do you add the question to the main form? Is it a window in the window or is it a Panel/User control?

Comment: I add the question to the main form using this function:

Comment: What function? Edit your thread instead.

Comment: Take a look at user controls and DockStyle.Top. I would like to help you more but I can't get my head around your code. I can't see where you actually add stuff to your main window. All I can see from your code is how you create the question form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the counter on the main form:

```
Public iCount As Integer
```

And then modify the location with any of this properties:

```
question.Top = iCount
iCount += question.Height + 10
```

--

```
question.Location = New Point(xVal, iCount)
iCount += question.Height + 10
```

Another possibility could be detect the last added question:

```
Dim lastQ As Control = Form1.Controls(Form1.Controls.Count - 1)
question.Top = lastQ.Top + lastQ.Height + iMargin
```

Comment: The problem is that when I call the child form from the main form, it creates a new form so there will be no way for me to save the counter position and pass that to the child form.  I was thinking of maybe using an array to store the questions, so that whenever they add a new question, it will just add it to the array, and the main form can merely read from the array but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: @user1668123 It doesnt matter you create a new form, you still have the main form on the background without closing it isnt it? You can access its data:  `MainForm.iCount += 10`

Comment: I think the problem is that the data that is entered in the child form is not being stored anywhere, so when I create the next question, it is getting overwritten.

Comment: @user1668123 So then add the controls directly on the main form. And if you want to store some data, use public variables on the main form, because the data stored on the new form will be lost on form closing

Comment: I am adding the controls dynamically because the user may enter 1 questions or up to 40 questions in the questionaire.  I dont want to add 40 textboxes if the user is only going to populate 2 of them.